# How to detect the position of some texts inside a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In Youtrack application, I find that they used some < li> tag next to input element to display the underlines, but I don't know how they can detect the position of texts inside the input element. Please see the image here [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this logic

- Create a duplicate element
- Populate the duplicate element content with input box content
- Calculate width of duplicate element (*The returned width will be the width of the text inside duplicate element*)

Remember the font size for both the elements i.e the text box and duplicate element should be the same : - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/74ocd65d/6/)**

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="evaluates(this)" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function evaluates(dis)
{
 alert(getWidth(dis));   
}
function getWidth(dis)
{
    var prev = document.getElementById("created_one");
    if(prev)
        document.body.removeChild(prev);

    var value = dis.value;
    var box = document.createElement("span");
    box.setAttribute("id","created_one");
    box.style.width="auto";
    box.style.border = "0px"
    box.style.padding = "0px";
    box.style.visibility = "hidden";
    box.style.position = "absolute";
    box.style.zIndex = "-1";
    box.style.bottom = "0px";
    box.innerHTML = value;
    document.body.appendChild(box);
    return parseInt( box.offsetWidth );
}
```

[Reference](http://www.codesandscripts.com/2014/09/detect-width-of-text-inside-html-text-input-box.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you can use `textarea.selectionStart` to retrieve the caret position.

This is one method which inserts dummy characters where-ever the cursor is and gets the position of the text rather than the cursor.

```
var area = document.getElementById("textareaID"); // the textarea 
area.focus(); // assign focus
var c = "{{#$%&{}"; // dummy string
var sel = document.selection.createRange();
var sel2 = sel.duplicate();
sel2 .moveToElementText(area);
sel.text = c;
pos = (sel2.text.indexOf(c));
```

Or this is a cross browser method which checks whether or not selectionStart is supported

```
var pos = 0;

if("selectionStart" in el) {
    pos = el.selectionStart;
} else if("selection" in document) {
    el.focus();
    var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
    var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
    Sel.moveStart("character", -el.value.length);
    pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
}
return pos;
```

---

There are also additional plugins for jQuery to manipulate the caret.  http://plugins.jquery.com/caret/

---

And here are a couple of jsFiddle demo's I came across

- http://jsfiddle.net/tEnY8/4/
- http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/aFPA7/

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a combination of the answers of dcc and shadow. But there're also some modifications to make it really work.

> 1. To make the duplicate span get exactly the same width as the text in input box, the font should be considered and the span's `white-space` css property should be set to `pre` to preserve the width of white space.
> 2. The margin, padding and border width of input box should be considered.

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/29Lohyra/3/).

And the javascript code:

```
var widthSpan;
function getPhraseStartPosition(input, currentPhraseIndex) {
    console.log(currentPhraseIndex);
    if (widthSpan == undefined) {       
        widthSpan = document.createElement("span");
        var $span = $(widthSpan);
        var $input = $(input);
        //make sure they share the same font
        $span.css("font-size", $input.css("font-size"));
        $span.css("font-family", $input.css("font-family"));
        $span.css("font-weight", $input.css("font-weight"));
        widthSpan.style.width="auto";
        widthSpan.style.border = "0px"
        widthSpan.style.padding = "0px";
        //to preserve white spaces in the span
        widthSpan.style.whiteSpace = "pre";
        widthSpan.style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.body.appendChild(widthSpan);
    }
    currentPhraseIndex = currentPhraseIndex == 0 ? 0 : currentPhraseIndex + 1;
    widthSpan.innerText = input.value.substring(0, currentPhraseIndex);
    var width = widthSpan.offsetWidth;
    return width;
}
function getPhraseIndex(input) {
    var caretIndex = 0;
    var value = input.value;
    if (input.selectionStart != undefined) {
        caretIndex = input.selectionStart;
    }
    else {
        var seletion = document.selection.createRange();
        seletion.moveStart("character", -value.length);
        caretIndex = seletion.text.length;
    }
    var currentPhraseIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < caretIndex; i++) {
        if (value.charAt(i) == ' ') currentPhraseIndex = i;
    }
    return currentPhraseIndex;
}
var shifting;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $input = $("#test");
    shifting = parseInt($input.css("padding-left")) 
        + parseInt($input.css("margin-left")) + parseInt($input.css("border-left-width"));
    function changeMarker() {
        $("#marker").css("width", getPhraseStartPosition(this, getPhraseIndex(this)) + shifting);
    }
    $input.keyup(changeMarker);
    $input.click(changeMarker);
});
```